# Flash AS3 : how to stop data loading before completion?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, download, loader

I'm developing a system which uses resources(image/sound) from server. On user action, I download specific resources and use them.

Now, before all those resources download completes, If user perform another action, I want to discontinue/cancel downloading current ones. Is this possible?

I tried with Loader.stop() method but it doesn't seems working as it should be.

Not canceling this slows down new resource downloading process and user has to wait for long for new resources.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit extreme, but would do it. Loader.close() should be enough.

```
    private var imageLoader:Loader;
    private function load(imageIndex:int = 0):void {
        //if it's already loading something. Cancels the current loading.
        if (imageLoader && imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo) {
            imageLoader.close();
            imageLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onImageLoaded);
            imageLoader = null;
        }
        imageLoader = new Loader();
        imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onImageLoaded);
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(staticVo.images[imageIndex].imageFile));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following: removed the Loader object and removed all its listeners.
Now, even if the system keep downloading the resource, there is no place to display it and also no event to call on complete/progress/fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop downloading the sound using the `close()` method of the [Sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#close()) class. This method

> Closes the stream, causing any download of data to cease. No data may be read from the stream after the `close()` method is called.

As for images and movies, the `Loader` class do have an `unload()` [method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#unload()), but I'm not sure if calling that method in the middle of the downloading will work.

Comment: I tried that as mentioned in question but, it dosen't seem to close stream. :(

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be of help:

http://onflash.org/ted/2007/12/progressive-image-loading-with.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it on a real server? The Flash IDE has a known bug that prevents `Loader.close()` from working correctly...